# Array filter with array loop inside

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, one with existing tags of book and another with searched results by user input value of tag to add and I need to show user tags to add that doesn't already exist in tags:

```
tags = [{id:1, name:'x'},{id:2, name:'y'},{id:5, name:'z'}]
search = [{id:2, name:'y'},{id:5, name:'z'},{id:15, name:'s'}]
```

How can I make a new array that will have search id's and other data that doesn't exist in tags array?

This is how it's worked for me in the end:

```
let newArray= search
  .filter(({ id }) => {
    return !tags.some(tag => {
      return tag.id == id
    })
  })
  .map(tag => {
    return (
      <Button
        key={tag.id}
      >
        {tag.name}
      </Button>
    )
  })
```

Comment: Use `indexOf` to check whether the current tags item you are looking at, is contained in search …?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript) and [check the difference between two arrays of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648091)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works for me:

```
let newArray= search
      .filter(({ id }) => {
        return !tags.some(tag => {
          return tag.id == id
        })
      })
      .map(tag => {
        return (
          <Button
            key={tag.id}
          >
            {tag.name}
          </Button>
        )
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` get all the values in the `object` in the `tags array.` Run a `filter` on the `search array` and if the `id` is not present in the above created `array` , return it

```js
var tags = [{id:1, name:'x'},{id:2, name:'y'},{id:5, name:'z'}]
var search = [{id:2, name:'y'},{id:5, name:'z'},{id:15, name:'s'}]
console.log(search.filter(({id,name})=>!tags.find(e=>e.id==id && e.name==name)))
```

Comment: updated question, there is many values in one item, so i need to save them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do it in a single line:

```js
const tags = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:5}];
const search = [{id:2},{id:5},{id:15}];

const result1 = search.filter(({ id }) => !tags.some(tag => tag.id === id));
const result2 = search.filter(({ id }) => !tags.find(tag => tag.id === id));

console.log(result1, result2);
```

If you use an older version of JavaScript, here is a version without arrow functions and destructuring:

```js
const tags = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:5}];
const search = [{id:2},{id:5},{id:15}];

const result1 = search.filter(search => { return !tags.some(tag => { return tag.id === search.id; }); });
const result2 = search.filter(search => { return !tags.find(tag => { return tag.id === search.id; }); });

console.log(result1, result2);
```

Comment: You can use `some` instead of `find`

Comment: @adiga, you are totally right, I will update the answer

Comment: you need to add return for .some

Comment: @RTW, no you don't need that as there is no block around it so the return is implicit

Comment: without return it doesn't work for me for some reason. Added worked version in question.

Comment: @RTW, I added an example without arrow function, that should work in your case

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the desired result in the example is `{id:15}`, since 15 is the only value in search that is not present in tags.

In that case, you should filter the search array, rather than the tags one. The condition is that the searched is not found in tags. The `find` method comes to the rescue here.

The actual code may look like this

```
let filtered = search.filter(searched =>
    !tags.find(tagged => tagged.id === searched.id)
)
```

Hope it helps - Carlos

Comment: ye, but i used some instead of find

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
search.filter(searchTag => tags.every(tag => tag.id != searchTag.id))
```

Comment: `!arr.some(x => x === anything)` is equivalent to `arr.every(x => x !== anything)` and the latter is easier to read because it doesn't rely on keeping the `!` in mind for the entire rest of the expression.